# Combine multiple sagas

Tags: redux, redux-saga

For combine multiple sagas I used

```
function* mySaga() {
    yield takeEvery("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser);
    yield takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', incrementAsync);
}
```

but I saw other design pattern :

```
function* mySaga() {

    yield all([
        yield takeEvery("USER_FETCH_REQUESTED", fetchUser),
        yield takeEvery('INCREMENT_ASYNC', incrementAsync)
    ]);

}
```

What diffferences between  ? Where we can use  yield all ?

Answer (score 2):

The `all` effect allows you to execute effects in parallel. For example, say you need to make 2 network calls and await their result before continuing:

```
const result1 = yield call(fetch, '/foo')
const result2 = yield call(fetch, '/bar')
```

In this case, result2 will not execute until result1 is resolved.

```
const [ result1, result2 ] = yield all([
  call(fetch, '/foo'),
  call(fetch, '/bar'),
])
```

In this case both `fetch` requests are fired off right after eachother without waiting for either to resolve. Once both have resolved, redux-saga will continue the generator function with the result of both promises.

Comment: Note: You only `yield` the result of `all([..])` when using this effect. If you'd yield every effect inside the list of effects passed to `all` it would still be blocking every effect until the previous is resolved.